# Angular http caching - hash vs html5mode

Tags: javascript, caching, angularjs, http-headers

Here's the thing, we want to be able to cache our partials(templates), using http headers.

After some thought we ended up with wanting to put our templates to the initially loaded html using the `script` directive.

Which would work just fine, as long as the url will use the hash(`index.html#/some/thing/123`). Since `index.html` would be cached no matter what I put after the hash.

Now what if I want to use the html5mode? Since the url is the key for caching `index/some/thing/123` and `index/some/thing/321` wouldn't be loaded from the cache, even though it'd still be the same `index.html`.. am I making any sense so far?

How can html5mode and http caching work along? Other than putting all the templates to a separated file?

..a little extra question, one of the reasons we wanted to use the script directive and not load the partials in a separated request because the only way I came up with(to load all the partials), would be to load them in say json file with key=>val, then run thru it and `.put()` them in the `$templateCache`, which is far from ideal. Is there a way to say load a file full of `script` directives? I can't really imagine how fast would this be, since it'd have to treat it as dom nodes and iterate over them to save it to the `templateCache`, which I think would be easier to work with, but even slower than the json approach..

Thanks!